# Trying to update libpython3.6-stdlib results in overwrite error

Tags: python, python-3.x, upgrade, python-3.6, apt-get

Here are the error logs which I get try to update the dependency.
I feel --overwrite flag can do the job with "dpkg" but I am not sure whether to use it or not as I see some cross dependency down there.
Thank you so much for your help.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.6-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.6-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,989 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,393 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 225358 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-5~16.04.york1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.5-5~16.04.york1) over (3.6.5-5~16.04.york0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-5~16.04.york1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/refactor.py', which is also in package python3-lib2to3 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-5~16.04.york1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

apt-cache policy libpython3.6-stdlib python3-lib2to3
gives this

```
libpython3.6-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.6.5-5~16.04.york0
  Candidate: 3.6.5-5~16.04.york1
  Version table:
     3.6.5-5~16.04.york1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.6.5-5~16.04.york0 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3-lib2to3:
  Installed: 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
  Candidate: 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`

Comment: Please can you add the output of the command `apt-cache policy libpython3.6-stdlib python3-lib2to3` to your question?

Comment: I'm getting this, installing on Ubuntu 16.04 from ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 repo

Comment: @Josh apt-cache policy libpython3.6-stdlib python3-lib2to3   looks like above

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo dpkg --install --force all /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.5-5~16.04.york1_amd64.deb
```

It solved same issue (hope without any broken)

Comment: This did it I guess, now visible problems till now. Thank you so much

Comment: This did it for me as well, but at some points the package wasn't in `archives/`.  I got a lot of messages about overwriting things, but afterwards `apt upgrade` completed successfully.  Thanks!

Comment: what's causing this issue?

Comment: Same problem (but with python 3.7). Fixed with this, but I'd very much be interested in what causes this

Comment: had a slightly different file that was giving me issues, but just copying the filename and doing the same `sudo dpkg --install --force all <filepath of .deb file>` on it worked for me too! (old Ubuntu 16.04 desktop)

Comment: Just had the same issue with `libpython3.10` (`libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+bionic2_amd64.deb` and `libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+bionic2_amd64.deb`). Is that an issue with package deps definitions ? It seem logical that these two packages share a conflicting file. The problem seems to be that other packages depend on stdlib vs minimal version of it. Perhaps our package managers cannot deal with `stdlib` version being a superset of `minimal`, thus a valid replacement or such...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in) except with a different package: python3-lib2to3 instead of scala. Try purging the problem package with

```
sudo dpkg -P python3-lib2to3
```

I had this same problem with python3-tk and that fixed it for me.

Comment: are you sure, isn't the cross dependency an issue here ??

Comment: trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib2to3/refactor.py', which is also in package python3-lib2to3 3.6.5-3~16.04.york0.2   i mean this line btw

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P python3-lib2to3
[sudo] password for asmuth:         
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of python3-lib2to3:
 python3-distutils depends on python3-lib2to3 (>= 3.6.4).

dpkg: error processing package python3-lib2to3 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-lib2to3`

Comment: Oh fun. :( Despite the similar error message in your original question, your problem seems a bit more complex than mine or the one in the issue I linked. If I were in your place, I might try purging python3-distutils. If things are in a weird dependency state, starting fresh may help. However, I'm not sure that's good advice. :) Sorry I can't be more helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I downloaded

```
sudo apt-get download python3.6=3.6.5-3 python3.6-minimal=3.6.5-3 libpython3.6-stdlib=3.6.5-3 libpython3.6-minimal=3.6.5-3
```

And then

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-downgrade \*3.6.5\*
```

And Done! I got it back!

This post was the first one that worked for me after updating to Mint 19.